# Drupal 8 overriding session management

Tags: php, session, drupal, drupal-8

I would like to override drupals core session management in favor of my own which instead saves the session to Redis rather than to the database.

After googling there is not much to go on except this:
https://www.drupal.org/project/session_proxy

The only issue is that isn't compatible with Drupal 8 and I only want so save to Redis I don't need any other handler.

In Symfony I created a session handler service but seems far more tricky in Drupal 8.

Any suggestions on how I should proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I thought the simplest way to fix this issue without relying on 3rd party modules or any other plugins was to override Drupals core SessionHandler class.

Firstly in my module I created a ServiceProvider class which instructs the container to redefine the core SessionHandler class definitio with my own. I didn't need the Database connection service so I made sure only the request stack was being passed to the constructor.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module;

use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceProviderBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class OoAuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->getDefinition('session_handler.storage')
            ->setClass('Drupal\my_module\SessionHandler')
            ->setArguments([
                new Reference('request_stack')
            ]);
    }
}
```

I then proceeded to create my own Redis SessionHandler:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module;

use Drupal\Component\Utility\Crypt;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\DependencySerializationTrait;
use Drupal\Core\Utility\Error;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Proxy\AbstractProxy;

/**
 * Default session handler.
 */
class SessionHandler extends AbstractProxy implements \SessionHandlerInterface {

    use DependencySerializationTrait;

    /**
     * The request stack.
     *
     * @var RequestStack
     */
    protected $requestStack;

    /**
     * @var \Redis
     */
    protected $redis;

    /**
     * SessionHandler constructor.
     *
     * @param RequestStack $requestStack
     */
    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        // TODO: Store redis connection details in config.
        $this->redis = (new PhpRedis())->getClient('redis-host', 6379);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function open($savePath, $name)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function read($sid)
    {
        $data = '';

        if (!empty($sid)) {
            $query = $this->redis->get(Crypt::hashBase64($sid));
            $data = unserialize($query);
        }

        return (string) $data['session'];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function write($sid, $value)
    {
        // The exception handler is not active at this point, so we need to do it
        // manually.

        var_dump(['Value', $value]);
        try {
            $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
            $fields = [
                'uid' => $request->getSession()->get('uid', 0),
                'hostname' => $request->getClientIP(),
                'session' => $value,
                'timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME,
            ];

            $this->redis->set(
              Crypt::hashBase64($sid),
              serialize($fields),
              (int) ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime")
            );

            return true;
        }
        catch (\Exception $exception) {
            require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/core/includes/errors.inc';
            // If we are displaying errors, then do so with no possibility of a
            // further uncaught exception being thrown.
            if (error_displayable()) {
                print '<h1>Uncaught exception thrown in session handler.</h1>';
                print '<p>' . Error::renderExceptionSafe($exception) . '</p><hr />';
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function close()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function destroy($sid)
    {
        // Delete session data.
        $this->redis->delete(Crypt::hashBase64($sid));

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function gc($lifetime)
    {
        // Redundant method when using Redis. You no longer have to check the session
        // timestamp as the session.gc_maxlifetime is set as TTL on write.
        return true;
    }

}
```

The PhpRedis used in my own implementation of the SessionHandler is just a small utility class for dealing with connecting to Redis.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module;

/**
 * Class PhpRedis
 * @package Drupal\oo_auth
 */
class PhpRedis implements ClientInterface
{
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
    public function getClient($host = null, $port = null, $base = null, $password = null)
    {
        $client = new \Redis();
        $client->connect($host, $port);

        if (isset($password)) {
            $client->auth($password);
        }

        if (isset($base)) {
            $client->select($base);
        }

        // Do not allow PhpRedis serialize itself data, we are going to do it
        // oneself. This will ensure less memory footprint on Redis size when
        // we will attempt to store small values.
        $client->setOption(\Redis::OPT_SERIALIZER, \Redis::SERIALIZER_NONE);

        return $client;
    }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
    public function getName() {
        return 'PhpRedis';
    }
}

<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module;

/**
 * Interface ClientInterface
 * @package Drupal\oo_auth
 */
interface ClientInterface
{
    /**
     * Get the connected client instance.
     *
     * @param null $host
     * @param null $port
     * @param null $base
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getClient($host = NULL, $port = NULL, $base = NULL);

    /**
    * Get underlying library name used.
    *
    * This can be useful for contribution code that may work with only some of
    * the provided clients.
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getName();
}
```

There is no suggested documentation out there (that I could find) that gives you an example of how to use Redis (this would in fact work with any datastore) as session store for your Drupal installation. There are posts about how to get it up and running with other 3rd party modules which is fine but I didn't want the extra fluff.

Comment: Hey Kal, would you have a zip with your module? I want to see if I can get it implemented in my Drupal project.

Comment: Hey André, I don't unfortunately as it was with the previous company I was with. However if you need assistance please feel free to email me and I will do my best to help: justlikephp@gmail.com :)

Answer (score 2):

There is an alpha release of the Redis module. If it's current limitations are not show-stoppers then you can just use this and configure as documented.
https://www.drupal.org/project/redis

See the docs for full details on config settings but as a starter, after installing the module you would add something like this to your settings.php

```
$settings['cache']['default'] = 'cache.backend.redis';
$settings['redis.connection']['host'] = '<<redis_host>>';
$settings['redis.connection']['port'] = '<<redis_port>>';
```

Where 'redis_host' and 'redis_port' are set according to your Redis instance.

Comment: I know it say "cache" but would it also stick session in redis?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with this Redis module. I managed to get it using Redis for the cache and it works great. However, still no luck on trying to get the sessions also in Redis

Comment: The current release for D8 Redis module doesn't support sessions but there is work on a sub-module that will. See this thread https://www.drupal.org/project/redis/issues/2876099